# How to enable default copy/paste option in edittext in popup window?

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llMain"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter here"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to paste programmatically.

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
String pasteData = "";

 // If it does contain data, decide if you can handle the data.
if (!(clipboard.hasPrimaryClip())) {

} else if (!(clipboard.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType(MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN))) {

    // since the clipboard has data but it is not plain text

} else {

    //since the clipboard contains plain text.
    ClipData.Item item = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);

    // Gets the clipboard as text.
    pasteData = item.getText().toString(); 
}
```

Comment: No i want to display default copy/paste option in edit text.

Comment: just add the `android:textIsSelectable="true"` atribute and you are done